# How to rotate Graphics3D perpendicular to the screen?

Tags: graphics3d

The [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InteractiveGraphics3DInteraction.html) say I can move to corner to the graphic to start rotation in direction perpendicular to the screen, yet in my own 3D plots, this doesn't work, any idea how to turn it on? (Mathematica 12.3.1 on MacOS)

```
Plot3D[1, {x, y} \[Element] Annulus[]]
```

[image]

Comment: Weird. This _used_ to work. But also for me it doesn't anymore, neither with version 12.0.0 nor with 12.3.1 on macos 10.15.7. Please file a bug report.

Comment: With Windows 10, *Mathematica* 12.3.0 the "tutorial/InteractiveGraphics3DInteraction" does show the "3D vertical rotate pointer" and does what it says.  However, those 3D objects are not created with `Plot3D`.  Creating a graphic with `RegionPlot3D` does show the 3D vertical rotate pointer.  So to continue with my ignorance, it must be that `Plot3D` doesn't product a 3D object as `RegionPlot3D` does.  But using `FullForm` on a `Plot3D` command does show that it results in a `Graphics3D` object.  ????

Comment: What I usually do to figure these out is to look at the `Options` of the result, and see if there is anything there (documented or undocumented) that may change how rotation works. Usually, this would be found in `Method`. I see a setting for `RotationControl` and a lot of settings for `DefaultGraphicsInteraction`. These look like a good starting point for an investigation. I won't have time for this, but perhaps someone else can give it a go?

Comment: Ah, the rotate pointer does work  in "conventional" `Graphics3D`-object...

Comment: Aaah, @Szabolcs, a whole new world is opening up for me...! `Plot3D[1, {x, y} \[Element] Annulus[], 
 Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "ArcBall"}]` seems to solve this.

Comment: Just curious: Can someone say when the 3D rotate pointer used to work with the Plot3D command (i.e. which version had this functionality before it disappeared)? `Annulus` is a rather recent addition, but even with `{x,0,1},{y,0,1}` ?